# Mathematical Olympiad Treasures Problem 1.92 how does this relate to geometric sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

You are supposed to show that if

$a,b,c$ are nonzero real numbers

and

$(ab+bc+ca)^3 =abc(a+b+c)^3$

$a, b, c$ are terms of a geometric sequence.

One given solution is that:

$(ab+bc+ca)^3 −abc(a+b+c)^3 = (a^2 −bc)  (b^2 −ac)  (c^2 −ab)$

How does the new factorization imply that $a,b,c$ are part of geometric sequence?

Comment: So, at least one of the multiplicands is zero, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got $(ab+bc+ca)^3 −abc(a+b+c)^3 = (a^2 −bc)  (b^2 −ac)  (c^2 −ab)$. Now since $(ab+bc+ca)^3 =abc(a+b+c)^3$, it implies $(ab+bc+ca)^3 −abc(a+b+c)^3=0$. Then;

$$(a^2 −bc)  (b^2 −ac)  (c^2 −ab)=0$$

This implies one of $(a^2 −bc),(b^2 −ac),(c^2 −ab)$ must be zero. Then we have $a^2 =bc$ or  $b^2 =ac$ or $c^2 =ab$.

If $a^2=bc$, then $b,a,c$ or $c,a,b$ in G.P. Similar for other cases.

Comment: To clarify to others why '$a^2=bc$ implies $b,a,c$ or $c,a,b$ is in a G.P'. Suppose $a=xr^k$ (the standard form of a term in a G.P) (this is possible because $a$ is a real ), then $a^2=x^2r^{2k}=bc$ we can thus say $b=xr^{2k−n}$ and $c=xr^{n}$ for some $n$

Comment: @Abe suppose you have $b\leq a\leq c$ and you also got $a^2=bc$, then take $a=xr$, you should have $b=x, c=xr^2$. Then $b,a,c$ in G.P., here $r\geq 1$

Comment: on the other hand suppose you have $c\leq a\leq b$ and you also got $a^2=bc$, then take $a=xr$, you should have $c=x, b=xr^2$. Then $c,a,b$ in G.P., here $r\geq 1$

Comment: @Abe The whole point of writing $a^2=bc$ implies $b,a,c$ or $c,a,b$ is G.P. is you do not have the info that $r>1$ or $r<1$ and $b<a<c$ or $c<a<b$, but one thing for sure that $a$ will be in at the middle, that's all.